# Issues Realtak ethernet driver ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4 building rtl r8101-1.037.01 driver

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I have Realtek RTL 810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller for my Laptop running on Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel version 5.4.0-1074-gke. When i try to update ubuntu this driver is missing and i downloaded the source code of driver from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100m-fast-ethernet-pci-express-software
I downloaded the driver for ubuntu and when i tried to build r9101-1.037.01
Below is the error

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1074-gke'
  CC [M]  /home/gowtham/RTLdriver/r8101-1.036.00/src/r8101_n.o
/home/gowtham/RTLdriver/r8101-1.036.00/src/r8101_n.c:11288:28: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct net_device *, unsigned int)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘void (*)(struct net_device *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
11288 |         .ndo_tx_timeout  = rtl8101_tx_timeout,
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/gowtham/RTLdriver/r8101-1.036.00/src/r8101_n.c:11288:28: note: (near initialization for ‘rtl8101_netdev_ops.ndo_tx_timeout’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:270: /home/gowtham/RTLdriver/r8101-1.036.00/src/r8101_n.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1762: /home/gowtham/RTLdriver/r8101-1.036.00/src] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1074-gke'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:117: modules] Error 2
```

I cannot connect via Ethernet or WiFi as it is based on QCA9377 chipset and driver is also missing. Can you please help on this.

Comment: from look of realtek webside it is for kernel up to 5.17.

Answer (score 0):

Please download this file on some other computer: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-gke/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1074-gke_5.4.0-1074.79_amd64.deb Transfer it on a USB key or similar to the desktop of your Ubuntu computer.

Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/linux*.deb
```

Reboot. Your ethernet and wireless should be working.

Comment: Thanks it works  driver is working fine now.

Comment: Glad it's working! If my answer has been useful, please acceot it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: After rebooting my Linux still I face same issue. Tried installation of Deb but no help

Comment: Please run: `uname -r` Is your kernel version still 5.4.0-1074-gke? If not, can you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and does the wireless work there?